# Why is Haystack AutoQuery called twice?

Tags: python, django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using ElasticSearch and Haystack to implement the search functionality.

After configuring everything, I created a custom view that inherits from `SearchView`:

```
class CustomSearchView(SearchView):
    """
    Search view of haystack.
    """
    template_name = 'search/search.html'
    form_class = ItemSearchForm
    context_object_name = 'items'
```

and urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^', CustomSearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
)
```

Search is working fine. However I noticed that every time I do a search, two requests are sent to `ElasticSearch`. I could see that in `elasticsearch_requests.log`

After some analysis I found that `AutoQuery` view from `haystack.inputs` is being called twice.

I want to reduce it to one so that there will be no additional pressure on elasticsearch backend.

Why is it called twice? How to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#haystack-iterator-load-per-query) haystack loads only 10 items per request. But you can change that by setting HAYSTACK_ITERATOR_LOAD_PER_QUERY variable in your settings.py.
Hope that helps.